# Can we distribute SharePoint DLLs with our application

Tags: client-object-model, object-model, console-application

1. Is my understanding of following page correct that we can distribute Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll with our application? Like we reference these DLLs in our application and set "Copy Local" to "True"?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539757%28v=office.14%29.aspx

2. Can we also distribute Microsoft.SharePoint.dll with our application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, definitely.
2. No. But the real question is: why would you want to distribute these server-side DLLs? They only work on a SharePoint server...

Comment: I was thinking that to connect using SSOM you need only Microsoft.SharePoint.dll so if I can include it in my application it will work from client machine also, no?

Comment: No. SSOM only works in code deployed and run on one of the SharePoint server in the farm. Using Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in a client application is not supported, not legal, and will technically fail in most cases (since, at least, SSOM actually connects the SQL database, and there's very few chances you can do that from a client).